# How to change colors

Tags: color

I was trying my best to make in intro for my YouTube channel. I wanted to to some background color changes along with some text color changes in beat with the music. I can't for the life of me find a tutorial for it. Any links/ advice?

Comment: I'm not sure how much information you can get from an audio stream in Blender, but you'd almost certainly use Python to set vertex colors (though I could imagine a setup using Cycles).

Comment: Have a look at the [Animation Nodes addon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qoa4XWfJJBk) or search for [bake sound to fcurve](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+sound+bake+fcurve)